# TestNG not executing @BeforeMethod

Tags: java, testng

I would like to use the same instance of @BeforeMethod for my tests from different classes but It just wont work

```
 package com.code.theCode

 public class theConfiguration{

    @BeforeMethod(groups = {"example"}, alwaysRun = true)
    public void setupMethod(){
       System.out.println("inside setupMethod");
    }
 }
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
 package com.code.test

 public class theTest{

    @Test(groups = {"example"}, alwaysRun = true)
    public void setupMethod(){
       System.out.println("inside test");
    }
 }
```

testng.xml

```
<suite name="AllTests" verbose="1">
   <test name="AllTests">
     <groups>
       <run>
          <include name="example">
       </run>
      </groups>
      <packages>
         <package name="com.code.*" />
      </packages>
   </test>
```

When run my tests I get blank sys outs

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: How do you execute it?

Comment: If you're getting blank  sys outs then your `BeforeMethod` as well as your test are not being executed, so the problem isn't only the `BeforeMethod`.
How are you running the tests? IDE? console? with which arguments?

Comment: yes, passes and prints System.out.println("inside test"); but wont print the @BeforeTest syso...It dosnt show me errors it the logs :(

Comment: How are you running the tests? IDE? console? with which arguments?

Comment: Eclipse IDE, TestNG Run configuration pointing to the testng.xml suite file

Comment: O.k, Iv also added BeforeSuite with a syso in the Configuration class...and it prints:) but the second method BeforeMethod wont:(...

Comment: Not sure about it, but try adding `alwaysRun = true` to the `BeforeMethod`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an abstract class which include your configuration methods (what you want to use for more @Tests). After that extend your Test class with the created Abstract class. For example:

```
public abstract class configurationClass {

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod() {
    System.out.println("beforeMethod");
  }

}

public class testClass extends configurationClass {

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    System.out.println("test1");
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    System.out.println("test2");
  }

}
```

When you run the test class, the output will be:

```
beforeMethod
test1
beforeMethod
test2
```

Comment: Hi peetya, I have achieved this already but I don't want to use inheritance hence why I thought the xml approach would be better.

Comment: For some reason it will calls BeforeSuite in the configuration class but not BeforeMethod....BeforeMethod should be called before (AT-SIGN)Test runs, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure that you can achieve it only from xml.
Yes, beforeMethod runs before @Tests.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/testng-tutorial-5-suite-test/ ...It just wont work :(