# TestNG - Test ignored error message

Tags: testng

Execution is stopped after `@BeforeSuite` before `@BeforeMethod` would be executed. I use `(alwaysRun=true)` in each cases. It doesn't execute another test cases from suite. I got error message:

> Test ignored.

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void launchBrowser() throws Exception
{
    browser = BrowserFactory.launch(BrowserType.CHROME);
    logger.info("Browser Launched");
}

@AfterMethod(alwaysRun=true)
public void closeBrowser() throws Exception
{
    browser.close();
}

@AfterSuite(alwaysRun=true)
public static void tearDown() throws Exception
{
    Reporter.generateReport();
    SDK.cleanup();
}
```

Comment: Add a @Test method, I think it will be worked.
Please check the link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30118362/540195

Comment: @Amit : It is present in first testcase. Error comes from `BaseTest` class, which is extended by all the other testcases. Like: `public class LoginTest extends BaseTest{`

Comment: Then try with Group...It will work.

Comment: @Amit : Where to put this? `(alwaysRun=true, groups={"Regression"})` After all cases?

Comment: Please check this: http://websystique.com/java/testing/testng-groups-example/

Comment: @Amit : I see, but execution fails in BaseTest class, so these groups will not be processed in my LoginTest class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171205/discussion-between-plaidshirt-and-amit).

Answer (score 11):

Here, it looks like the case is mostly because of DataProvider. If you are using DataProvider and haven't set it up properly (like not returning proper 2D array, returning empty array etc) it will ignore the test method. So make sure your DataProvider is proper and run the test again.

Comment: Could you please provide an example from it?

Comment: @plaidshirt

`@DataProvider(name = "testData")
public Object[][] getTestData() {
return new Object[0][];
}`
Something like this will not give you any compile time error but TestNG will ignore the test in this case. Suppose you are depending on some other method to get the data needed to be passed on to this DataProvider and that data is coming empty will end up with ignored tests.

Comment: Another case you could mention is when your data provider method throws an exception. At least in my case (TestNG run from IntelliJ) the exception itself was not logged.

Comment: Kudos to you. 
Fixed the DataProvider and now it works like a charm... 
Unfortunately, nothing explicit was printed in the logs.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the similar issue , and thought its a compiler issue/ Testng Issue. 
But there was a problem in the way I was using dataprovider . Better put a debugger pointer in DataProvider function and debug you would be able to find the issue.

Env  : Java + SDK + IntelliJ

Comment: Problem differs person by person , you can keep the debug pointer in data provider and check why the tests are ignorefd

Answer (score 1):

Some times throwing skip exception is also shown as Test Ignored, please check in your framework if that is the case.