# unable to execute test when data provider is mentioned

Tags: selenium, appium, appium-android

When i add "dataProvider" and "dataProviderClass" to my APpium test i am getting below error,

```
[Configuration] [WARN] Detected a static method [genericLib.BaseClass.InitiateDriver()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
[Configuration] [WARN] Detected a static method [AppLogin.LoginTC.initialSetup()]. Static configuration methods can cause  unexpected behavior.
basepath /Users/sadanandak/Intellij-workspace/RetailerApp

Test ignored.

===============================================
Default Suite
Total tests run: 0, Passes: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Below is the @test ,

```
@BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    public static void initialSetup() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        PageInitialization.initializeAllpages(driver);
        Login.login();
    }

    @Test(enabled = true, groups = "Independent_TC",dataProvider = "LoginTestData_001",dataProviderClass = LoginDP.class)
    public void test(LinkedHashMap<String,String> dataMap) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
```

Below is the base class,

```
  protected static AppiumDriver driver;
    static Properties properties;


    @BeforeMethod
    public static void InitiateDriver() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capability.setCapability("platformName","Android");
        capability.setCapability("deviceName","emulator-5554");
        //capability.setCapability("deviceName","3ef1d3c67d29");
        capability.setCapability("automationName","UiAutomator2");
        capability.setCapability("app","/Users/sadanandak/Intellij-workspace/RetailerApp/src/apk/Distiman.apk");
        capability.setCapability("autoWebview", true);
        URL url = new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub") ;

        driver = new AppiumDriver(url,capability);
        //driver.launchApp();

    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void afterTest(){
        if(driver != null){
            driver.quit();
        }
    }
```

please let me know why my testcase is not getting executed when i add dataprovider.Once i remove data provider everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

Actually there was an issue in data provider scipt which is causing this whole issue.

Reference ticket [TestNG - Test ignored error message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50368108/testng-test-ignored-error-message/53221942)