# TESTNG - @BeforeClass and @BeforeMethod does not execute

Tags: java, selenium, annotations, testng

**TestNG.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="BDD Test Suite" verbose="1" parallel="tests" thread-count="3" >
    <test name="Chrome" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="runner.TestRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Safari" annotations="JDK" preserve-order="true">
        <parameter name="browser" value="safari"/>
        <classes>
          <class name="runner.TestRunner" />
        </classes>
    </test> 
</suite>
```

**Runner**

```
package runner;

import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests;
import io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;

@CucumberOptions(features = "something.feature", glue = {"definitions" })

public class TestRunner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests {

}
```

**definitions**

```
package definitions;

import io.cucumber.java.en.*;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Parameters;
import pom.loginPage;

public class LoginTests {
    
    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpCucumber() {
        //this part is not executed
    }

    @BeforeMethod(alwaysRun = true)
    @Parameters({ "browser" })
        public void setUp(String browser) {
        //this part is not executed
    }

    @Given("this is part of feature file")
    public void this_is_part_of_feature_file() {
        //this part is executed twice per TestNG.XML
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to Java and TestNG. I tried to simplify the above code. Please forgive me if it’s not well formatted.

When running the TestNG.XML as TestNG in eclipse, the parameters are passed in and the @Given part is executed twice => the XML is calling the definition file => the runner file is correctly written.

My problem is that @BeforeClass and @BeforeMethod are not executed. If I move these 2 to the Runner, then it’s executed; however, then my cucumber JSON is somehow empty.

Can someone assist to let me know why the @BeforeClass and @BeforeMethod are not executed even though I specify *alwaysRun=true*?

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105487/testng-not-executing-beforemethod#30118362

The answer says to use an abstract class for the configuration methods.

Comment: `however, then my cucumber JSON is somehow empty` what is `cucumber JSON` ?

Comment: cucumber JSON is JSON report generated using @CucumberOptions => plugin = "pretty". After meddling with the codes per Callanbr suggestion, everything seems to be working. Only thing is that the html report from pretty plugin shows "?" for the test test status even though the JSON contains "status":"passed" within.